# Is there a way to extract a member from a nested tagged union?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an `Integration` which is a discriminated union, and a `Stage` which is also a discriminated union that may contain an `Integration` in it.

```
type Integration = 
  | { type: "assessment-A",  apiKey: string }
  | { type: "assessment-B", clientKey: string, clientSecret: string }
  | { type: "assessment-C" }

type Stage = 
  | { type: "generic"; name: string }
  | { type: "assessment"; name: string; integration: Integration }
```

What I would like to be able to do is to define a type `AssessmentAStage` which is the particular member of this union which has both `type: "assessment"` and the particular integration with `type: "assessment-A"`.

Essentially it would be great to write this:

```
type AssessmentAStage = Extract<Stage, { type: "assessment", integration: { type: "assessment-A" } }>
```

However this comes out as `never`. Is it possible to define `AssessmentAStage` based on `Stage` with some more complex conditional types? I wasn't able to find a way.

Comment: `Stage & { type: "assessment", integration: { type: "assessment-A" } }` should do what you want for most purposes.

Comment: Thanks, that works although the resulting type is a bit odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you want would be an intersection type

```
type AssessmentAStage = Stage & {type: "assessment", integration: {type: "assessment-A"}}
```

This will work, but Typescript won't simplify the resulting type so it will still appear in hover tooltips or error messages as an intersection. If you want to create a type which reads more nicely, the below should work:

```
type AssessmentTypes = Integration['type'] extends `assessment-${infer T}` ? T : never
type AssessmentStage<T extends AssessmentTypes> = {
  type: "assessment",
  name: string,
  integration: Extract<Integration, {type: `assessment-${T}`}>
}

type AssessmentAStage = AssessmentStage<'A'>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdsCBzATgQ2ASwPZygXigFgAoKKAHygG8pRIAuKAIjQGc2IOBbCBAWgCCzADTk0YTAGkIIJm2ApMcJFAC+pclVr0ITVhy5teAgEKioAYwA2mPsBlyoCpSrE27CAMoRLKCMDyisqqGmSUNHTgeizsnDz2-ADCzOqkpLpQgoYJCAAq0WwEsAjI6Fi4ANoA5LrVALpQEAAeiHAAJkUABnFGJsD8ACTUygBmEChQeWpdUAD8U1BMcBAAbhMZ0Vk5xvZewGhIEAA8eU2tfJ3b8bv5hQB8xdSaUYyxO-2iL3BovEGuSBEL2UiFQGBwcCYAFFWuhLMBjvBQeUIWJqLomD0PolhtMump7qQwptINc+vZBPtDtBCNkbv0qUdjtVBNVCSRSAB6ABUJOgACUuABXazAJ4vDHven2ZgAbm+vxiLhC8vCILK4NwTGe4XIkoM0oEwlV5HEkkc-xVLzUqrC3M5pCAA)

Comment: Thanks, this works quite well. The only downside is that we need to redefine the other fields in `Stage` (`type`, `name`), so if we change `Stage` we need to remember to update `AssessmentStage` too.
I tried avoiding this by using a combination of `Omit` + `Exclude` + an intersection but the resulting type is quite ugly so I think it's not desirable.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could define `type Stage = AssessmentStage<AssessmentTypes>` to avoid repetition, though this may be less readable since it expands the union type for the `integration` property instead of writing it as `Integration`. You can change the `Extract` part to a conditional type ``AssessmentTypes extends T ? Integration : Extract<Integration, {type: `assessment-${T}`}>`` if readability is important.

Comment: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdsCBzATgQ2ASwPZygXigFgAoKKAHygG8pRIAuKAIjQGc2IOBbCBAWgCCzADTk0YTAGkIIJm2ApMcJFAC+pclVr0ITVhy5teAgEKioAYwA2mPsBlyoCpSrE27CAMoRLKCMDyisqqGmSUNHTgeizsnDz2-ADCzOqkpLpQgoYJCAAq0WwEsAjI6Fi4ANoA5LrVALpQEAAeiHAAJkUABnFGJsD8ACTUygBmEChQeWpdUAD8U1BMcBAAbhMZ0Vk5xvZewGhIEAA8eU2tfJ3b8bv5hQB8xdSaUYyxO-2iL3BovEGuSBEL2UiFQGBwcCY2Ru-QKkCKLTaVzOC3goPKEKWUAAoq10JZgMc0WVwbgxNRdEweh9EsNpl01PdSGFNpBrn17IJ9odoIRoRzvAcjsdqoJqkySKzoNyjsV+blgDKTvLbsA4VwJUA) for that edit.